# Rails bootstrap_checkbox not reflecting value of table - Showing all OFF

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I built a form for a table with mostly boolean values. The form displays well, the bootstrap toggle works well, it saves data well, but it displays all the value as OFF when the edit page is called again.

I have tried playing with the options. Adding checked_value and unchecked_value, but it does not work.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@setting) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-check_boxs">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <%= f.label :open_for_work  do %>
                <%= t :open_for_work %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <%= f.check_box :open_for_work,  options: {}, checked_value: "true", unchecked_value: "false" %>
            </div><% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <%= f.label :turn_app_local  do %>
                <%= t :turn_app_local%>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <%= f.check_box :turn_app_local,  options: {}, checked_value: "true", unchecked_value: "false"  %>
            </div><% end %>
          </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Does anyone knows how to actually  use the gem 'bootstrap-switch-rails' in rails ? 
NB: My site is all in Bootsrap 4, could be the reason why this does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap issue should just affect styling and not the actual params passed through. Try:

```
<%= f.input :status, :as => :check_boxes, collection: [['true', 'false']]  %>
```

Note that these will pass the strings 'true' and 'false' respectively when selected or not.

Comment: Hey Mark, this solution does not work for me actually. The toggle shows up, but it no longer works, and it has written "true" on its right.